# Redesign UI using DIV and not tables

Tags: html, css, html-table

I'm currently trying to convert the following layout below from table to div. It has the following features:

1. 100% in width and height (in relation to browser window size)
2. Top half takes up 80% of 100%, bottom half takes 20%
3. Top section scrolls in y direction when text overflows, fixed header does not move with scroll however the text below (lorem ipsum...) will move underneath it
4. Bottom section does not scroll at all

How can I accomplish this in DIV and not tables?

[image]

This is my code so far: http://jsfiddle.net/zhz2m/1/

```
<table width="100%" height="100%" id="container">
  <tr>
    <td height="85%" id="top"><div id="chat" style="height: 100%; overflow: scroll-y">
        <h2>Innovation Week 2013 - Virtual Idea Wall</h2>
      </div></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td height="10%" id="bottom"><form id="send-message">
        <p>
          <label for="title">Please give your idea a title</label>
          <br />
          <input type="text" id="title" name="title"/>
        </p>
        <p>
          <label for="message">Please provide details of your idea</label>
          <br>
          <input type="text" id="message" name="message"/>
        </p>
        <p>
          <input type="submit">
        </p>
        </input>
      </form></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at this fiddle:

define height, position fixed, and overflow behaviour.

http://jsfiddle.net/63bjC/1/

CSS:

```
#main {
    width: 100%;
    height: 80%;
    min-height: 80%;
    max-height: 80%;
    position: fixed;
    overflow: scroll;
}

#footer {
    width: 100%;
    height: 20%;
    min-height: 20%;
    max-height: 20%;
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    background-color: orange;
}
```

Markup:

```
<div id="main">content</div>
<div id="footer">fixed at bottom</div>
```